# Is there a list of all ASCII characters in python's standard library?

Tags: python

Is there a field or a function that would return all ASCII characters in python's standard library?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants) module:

```
import string
print string.printable
```

which gives:

```
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```

Comment: I can't say for sure that this isn't what they were looking for, but ASCII defines several non-printable characters, too.

Comment: This is the only answer that answers the question, technically. string.printable is a variable (or for the purposes of the question, effectively such, if it isn't literally).

Answer (score 30):

You can make one.

```
ASCII = ''.join(chr(x) for x in range(128))
```

If you need to check for membership, there are other ways to do it:

```
if c in ASCII:
    # c is an ASCII character

if c <= '\x7f':
    # c is an ASCII character
```

If you want to check that an entire string is ASCII:

```
def is_ascii(s):
    """Returns True if a string is ASCII, False otherwise."""
    try:
        s.encode('ASCII')
        return True
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False
```

Comment: I was actually looking for this very answer, but note that it will not be very obvious what you are doing here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any included python module that has such a attribute. However, the easiest and shortest way is probably just to create it yourself

```
standard_ascii = [chr(i) for i in xrange(128)]
```

or

```
extended_ascii = [chr(i) for i in xrange(256)]
```

for the extended ascii character list.

Note that

```
import string
string.printable
```

does not include all of the 127 standard ascii characters, which you can see by

```
len(string.printable)
> 100
```

If you want them as string instead of a list, just add an `"".join()`, like so:

```
extended_ascii = "".join([chr(i) for i in xrange(256)])
```

Comment: What was maybe formerly called "extended ASCII" is nowadays one of many possible character sets which all are (mostly) mutually exclusive. So there really is no such thing as "extended ASCII".

Comment: Then let's maybe talk about 7-bit and 8-bit ASCII to be more precise

Comment: I'm not sure the "extended ASCII" works using the method above - for example, the first character in extended ascii (Windows-1252) is the Euro character €, but the first character generated by `chr(128)` is `\0x80` which in Unicode is some weird `pad` character. You get a € with `chr(8364)`. The perceptual problem is that `chr()` is keyed to ascii in other languages, but is keyed to Unicode in Python. N.B. I only realise this after coding something very similar to the above, and later discovering it's failing to match certain characters I'd have expected it to find.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Python Standard Library module [`curses.ascii`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.ascii.html). Some of the included functions include:

```py
curses.ascii.isascii() # Checks for a character value in the 7-bit ASCII set.
curses.ascii.iscntrl() # Checks for an ASCII control character (in the range 0x00 to 0x1f).
curses.ascii.isalpha() # Check for an ASCII alphabetic character.
```

From the documentation:

> The [`curses.ascii`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.ascii.html) module supplies name constants for ASCII characters and functions to test membership in various ASCII character classes.

Note that the [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module is may not be available on a Windows system:

> The [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module provides an interface to the curses library, the de-facto standard for portable advanced terminal handling.
>
> While curses is most widely used in the Unix environment, versions are available for DOS, OS/2, and possibly other systems as well. This extension module is designed to match the API of ncurses, an open-source curses library hosted on Linux and the BSD variants of Unix.